# How to Use View.OnClickListener

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android, I have a problem in "View.OnClickListener".
I wrote some code, but my expected result has not come. Below is my code, Please tell what am I doing wrong.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View.OnClickListener button=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
                //note();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            }
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Does your project has a button in layout?

Comment: ya... it,s id = button1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set you click listener to the button. Add this in `onCreate`

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(button);
```

So this:

```
View.OnClickListener button=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            //note();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        }
        }

};
```

becomes:

```
View.OnClickListener button=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            //note();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        }
        }

};
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(button); // Set clicklistener to Button
```

Answer (score 0):

first search then question on stack. please have a look in this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/view/onclicklistener/android-onclicklistener-example/)

Comment: hello sir, i already  saw that tutorial. please try to understand my question.